# MySQL - Setting for implicit cast of string to number?

Tags: php, mysql

Where can I turn on/off the setting that causes implicit typecasting of string to decimal(15,3) for my numeric fields?

Some explanation of the issue:  I have two mysql servers, one for dev, one for production.  Running this query behaves differently on them.  The production server is externally hosted. The dev box I am admin on.

In the dev box, both these queries return the same 3 rows:

```
select * from tableX where Size = '2.330';
select * from tableX where Size = 2.330;
```

In production, this one returns 3 rows:

```
select * from tableX where Size = 2.330;
```

But this one in production returns empty set:

```
select * from tableX where Size = '2.330';
```

Unfortunately the code is actually using

```
select * from tableX where Size = '2.330';
```

So in production it doesn't work right. I'd like to make the two boxes match so I can fix it and be sure it will work in both.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-mode.html

Comment: Why not strictly enforce type in your query, which would be good practice anyway? If the field in the database is a decimal, query it as such, and don't put string delimiters around it.  Same for other non-string field types. Just hoping that you can loosely treat data types and things magically work is poor programming practice in general and you will run into problems with it at some point. This is one of the biggest problems with loosely typed languages, it can lead to bad development habits.

Comment: Try to use the same version of MySQL on both servers, dev and pro.

Comment: @Mike Brant, Its legacy code. I'm going to fix it in the next deployment but I thought in the meantime I could maybe change the setting as a quick fix.

Comment: And I did need to know how to make both servers behave the same too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might be not a solution for you but my idea ia why you not cast from code and pass correct type to mysql. Thats even better as it free mysql from doing cast